# XPages: Creating Json String from categorised view

Tags: java, xpages

I would  like to create a Json String from categorised view, using Java, but i have been unable to make the Json child category stay under the parent. i keep geting the below output:

> { "identifier":"id", "label":"State", "items": [

Would to know if it posible to generate JSON String from 2 level categorised View  or if there is a beter way to achive it.

below is my java method:

```
public ResponseWriter getJSONData() { 
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ResponseWriter resWriter = facesContext.getResponseWriter();

        //StringWriter stringOut = new StringWriter();
        JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(resWriter,false);
        Database db = null;

        try {
            writer.startObject();

            writer.startProperty("identifier");
            writer.outStringLiteral("id");
            writer.endProperty();

            writer.startProperty("label");
            writer.outStringLiteral("State");
            writer.endProperty();

            writer.startProperty("items");
            writer.startArray();

            db = DominoUtils.getCurrentSession().getCurrentDatabase();
            View lookupDB = db.getView("StateAndCity");         
            //Document doc = lookupDB.getFirstDocument();   

            ViewNavigator nav = lookupDB.createViewNav();
            ViewEntry ve = nav.getFirst();

            boolean run =false;
            while (ve != null){    
                counter++;
                Vector cv = ve.getColumnValues();
                int level = ve.getIndentLevel();
                String levelTitle = (String) cv.get(level);


                writer.startArrayItem();
                writer.startObject();

                if (ve.isCategory()) {

                    if (run) {
                        writer.endArrayItem();
                        writer.endArray();

                    } 
                    run= true;
                    writer.startArrayItem();

                    writer.startProperty("id"); 
                    writer.outStringLiteral(getID());
                    writer.endProperty();

                    writer.startProperty("title");
                    writer.outStringLiteral(levelTitle);
                    writer.endProperty();

                    writer.startProperty("category");
                    writer.outStringLiteral("true");
                    writer.endProperty();

                    writer.startProperty("children");
                    writer.startArray();

                }else{

                    writer.startArrayItem();
                    writer.startObject();

                    Document doc = ve.getDocument();


                    writer.startProperty("id"); 
                    writer.outStringLiteral(getID());
                    writer.endProperty();

                    writer.startProperty("docId"); 
                    writer.outStringLiteral(doc.getUniversalID());
                    writer.endProperty();

                    writer.startProperty("title");
                    writer.outStringLiteral(levelTitle);
                    writer.endProperty();

                    writer.startProperty("category");
                    writer.outStringLiteral("false");
                    writer.endProperty();

                    writer.endObject();
                    writer.endArrayItem();

                }    


                ViewEntry tmpentry = nav.getNext();

                ve.recycle();
                ve = tmpentry;
            }  

            writer.endArray();
            writer.endProperty();
            writer.endObject();


            long endTime   = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
            //System.out.println("running time:  "+totalTime);

            writer.flush();


            return resWriter;

        }catch (NotesException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resWriter;
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
Would like to use my return JSON to creat a grid of this below type but with two level category State and City

[image]

JSON output

```
{
    "identifier": "id",
    "label": "name",
    "items": [{
        "id": "AK",
        "type": "state",
        "state": "AK",
        "childItems": [{
            "id": "Anchorage",
            "type": "city",
            "city": "Anchorage",
            "numPeople": "2",
            "childItems": [{
                    "id": "B3093953178C98E905257838007ABC48",
                    "firstname": "Bella",
                    "lastname": "Martin",
                    "valueToAdd": "2"
                },
                {
                    "id": "7FDB9CCDE7D6923E05257838007ABC1E",
                    "firstname": "Brian",
                    "lastname": "Leggett",
                    "valueToAdd": "2"
                }
            ]
        }]

....
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code crashes before it can write anything. There are a few problematic statements:

- Vectors/Arrays are zero based, but `int level = ve.getIndentLevel();` is not, so you most likely get an index out of bound error
- If something returns null a cast to String will error too. so change `String levelTitle = (String) cv.get(level);` to `String levelTitle = String.valueOf(cv.get(level));`
- I would recommend change your method signature to something like `public String getJSONFromView(final Database db, final String viewName) {...}` Then have a bit of wrapper code to call that method. This allows you to use the class in a Domino command line app too which is very comfortable to debug in Designer/Eclipse locally. Since the class has no XPages dependency that makes life easier. I developed all of VoP that way: the core had no server, only Notes classes dependencies. You would create a test class like this (error handling omitted):

  ```
  public class Test1 {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
         NotesThread.sinitThread();
         Session s = NotesFactory.createSession();
         Database db = s.openDatabase("someserver","somedb");
         Yourclass yc = new Yourclass();
         System.out.println(yc.getJSONFromView(db,"viewname");
         db.recycle();
         s.recycle();
         NotesThread.stermThread();
     }
  }
  ```

You might need to switch to the Java perspective in Domino designer and create a standard Java project where you put that. That should allow you to make your Java class do what you want before you use it in your XPage.

I wrote something similar a while a go, you can [check it out](https://www.wissel.net/blog/2014/09/rendering-a-notes-view-as-json-rest-service-on-your-client.html).

Let us know what needs clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You could fall back to "old" Domino tricks and do away will all Java. Define the view as Passthru HTML and create a "$$ViewTemplate for ViewName" form with the mime type "text/Json". You then can access the output with ?Openview. Sprinkle Json markup as needed.

Or just use .../viewname?ReadviewEntries&Outputformat=json

Build in Json output

Comment: But unable to use to the output to create a TreeGrid, that is while i am using Java so to define what field needed or item to put together

Comment: OK, so you need a specific structure for your JSON. Could you amend your question with the output you need? There are two routes possible: JsonWriter and Json serilization. For the later GSON is a good choice (used e.g. in Verse on Prem)